# Automatic Gain Control when plugging external MIC in Android

Tags: android, audio, microphone

I´m aware that most of the devices have some built-in audio pre-processing features that cannot be disabled (as for example AGC). 
I´ve read in some places that setting the audio input to VOICE_RECOGNITION might disable the AGC, but what I´ve found so far is that this actually depends on the OEM.
My question is what happens when you plug in an external MIC into the device. Do we still have AGC applying in this situation? or it´s automatically disabled when the enternal MIC is connected? How can I find it out?

Thanks

Comment: A simple test for agc is to play a soft signal at a steady level while pulsing a louder one on and off.  Filter the loud one out of the recording and see if the level of the quiet one is steady, or if it is reduced when the loud one was present and activating the agc.